# How to assign more ranges to same variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to assign more ranges to variable.

The message "Run time error :invalid procedure call or argument"
appears on `Set bckup = Union(.Cells(3, i), bckup)` line.
I have tried to use function 'range'

Set bckup = Range(.Cells(3, i), bckup)

but also got message "method range of object _global failed"
or  `Set bckup = Range(.Cells(3, i) & bckup)`
and got "object variable or with block variable not set"

```
With Workbooks("Deactivate.xlsm").Worksheets(2)
For i = 500 To 2 Step -1

    If .Cells(3, i).Value <> "" Then

        If .Cells(7, i) = 0 Then

        'Run time error :invalid procedure call or argument
        Set bckup = Union(.Cells(3, i), bckup)

        bckup.Select
        End If

    End If
Next i
End With
```

I want to store all of range that meet criteria in a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first check whether `bckup` contains anything as you can't union with `Nothing`.

```
With Workbooks("Deactivate.xlsm").Worksheets(2)
    For i = 500 To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(3, i).Value <> "" Then
            If .Cells(7, i) = 0 Then
                If bckup Is Nothing Then
                    Set bckup = .Cells(3, i)
                Else
                    Set bckup = Union(.Cells(3, i), bckup)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
```